# How to find loop/ repetition in a data stream?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I came across an interesting question in an interview. But I couldn't answer it, neither I found it on Google.

Question is as follows:

> You are given a data stream. With the help of variable declaration how you can find whether there is any repetition or loop in the data.

Example of the data stream are:

```
100100100100
0001000100010001
100100010001
10...0010....010....01(where 0....0 is 0^10^10^10)
```

How can this problem be solved? Is there any algorithm for such kind of problem?

Answer (score 5):

I think there must two approaches to this problem

**1. Longest repeated substring problem**

This is well known problem which have solution in linear time. You have to construct `suffix tree` for your string then analyze it.
Please [check this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem) for details

**2. Repeated substring problem (any)**

You can modify `Longest repeated substring` to find any repeated substring.

Comment: It works for a string, yes, but I'm curious, does it work for a stream?

Comment: If you can wait for stream ends, you can use this algorithm for whole streamed data. If You must do it dynamically while stream, I think You can modify prefix tree construction algorithm, and then dynamically add new elements. and check every time new data comes with stream

Comment: @Gor sure, everything is possible to modify, but the algorithms you are referring are not quite suitable for the described problem...

Answer (score 3):

The brute force solution would be to use a map or a dictionary for that, i.e. for stream `100100100100` it will be:

```
dict["1"]++
dict["10"]++
dict["100"]++
dict["1001"]++
```

etc till the max length of the repetition to find. Then we drop the first symbol and repeat, i.e. `1` is dropped and `00100100100` is left to analyze:

```
dict["0"]++
dict["00"]++
dict["001"]++
dict["0010"]++
```

etc.

At the end we iterate over the map and print all keys with more than one value.

There are more efficient algorithms, but this is the easiest I guess.

Comment: @Fallen why not, we just need a buffer size `max_len_of_repetition_to_find` which will work as a sliding window...

Comment: yes it will with an extra parameter like max_len_of_repetition_to_find. But I was curious as the OP didn't mention any such parameter given.